# How do I change to ISO 8601 date format?

Tags: date

I want to use the ISO 8601 date format system wide with Ubuntu 12.04. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is not a single date format actually. There are variations differing in length and detail. You should probably first tell us which format you would like to have.

Comment: So the major issue is a system wide use of YYYY-MM-DD and 24hour clock. This would be solved with the Denmark regional format. But I would like to have "." as the decimal separator not the "," and the weeks starting with Monday.

Comment: See [this question for a partial solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/237941/how-to-configure-the-clock-date-format-to-iso-8601)