# How to configure the clock date format to ISO 8601 in Unity?

Tags: unity

By default, the time in AM/PM style is shown, I would like to have the same that `ls` gives:

```
2013-01-09 01:12
```

That is 24 hours and ISO 8601.  How can I do this?

I am aware of the following question. Maybe that question was too general to be answered:
[How do I change to ISO 8601 date format?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155845/how-do-i-change-to-iso-8601-date-format)

I tried the following:

1. I click on the actual clock-display and I get a calendar. In that calendar I read "Time & Date Settings.." - so I click on it: No effect. No nothing.
2. I right-click on the clock-display but I get the same calendar like when left-clicking on it.

Comment: If you're not locked into Unity, XFCE can do this easily. You can set a custom time format. Mine looks like this: %a, %Y-%b-%d, %I:%M %p

Comment: @wjandrea: Not helpful

Comment: @false How not?

Comment: @false The accepted answer on "How to change the date format" is very good. It explains how to set a custom format and what formats are available. Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: @wjandrea: 1mo, you suggest two different answers. 2do, there is nothing about ISO 8601 in that other question. 3tio, I went through it but failed (don't remember why). This accepted answer here was the first to work.

Comment: @false I'm not saying your question is bad or wrong, just that you can find the same answer on other questions.

Comment: @wjandrea: No, I can't, because of 2do and 3tio. Please read my responses.  also, you did not respond to 1mo.

Comment: @wjandrea: Thank you for recommending me to do "a bit of research"...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no easy way to do it in the GUI.  One can either use `dconf-editor` (which is GUI-*ish*), and edit two keys in `/com/canonical/indicator/datetime` (`time-format` to `custom`, and `custom-time-format` to the desired `strftime` directives, in your case `%F %R` (or, equivalently, `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M`)), or do it directly from the terminal with the following two commands (which, just to be clear, change the same keys):

```
dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/time-format "'custom'"
dconf write /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/custom-time-format "'%F %R'"
```

Note that the doubled quotes are necessary due to dconf's idiosyncracies. (For clarity, I'm referring to the nesting of single quotes (`'`) inside double quotes (`"`).) Note also that to include seconds, one can replace `%R` with `%T`.

I do not recall which release started including the dconf tools by default, so if they are unavailable, simply install the `dconf-tools` package and proceed.

Update 2016-05-17: While the above should still work, as a matter of principle it's probably better to access the dconf database via `gsettings set` than `dconf write` -- same database, but a tool more intended for end-users. The corresponding GUI-ish tool remains `dconf-editor`.

Comment: I see com.canonical.indicator.datetime in the dconf-editor, but there are no values to set. dconf also had no effect. I tried logging out. Maybe I have to place these lines somewhere? Prior to starting X ?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  They show up for me, and the dconf commands take effect immediately, too.  Which release art using?

Comment: It could be 11.10 related. I currently upgrade to 12.04. Will come back.

Comment: Ah.  I seem to recall there was some slightly odd interaction between `gconf` and `dconf` in Oneiric, although I could be wrong.  The methods I suggested work for me in both Precise and Quantal, though I haven't an Oneiric machine to hand with which to test.

Comment: Doesn't work in 13.04

Comment: @kaleissin WFM in 13.04 (just tested on a clean install).  Try doing it manually in the dconf-editor, which now appears to be installed by default.

Comment: Verified to work in 14.04 - I'd love to have `"%F, %R"` (above) added as an option in the GUI.

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/41961/9608) someone does it with `gsettings`.