# How do I change the date format in Gnome 3 shell?

Tags: gnome

I want to change the date/time format on the top panel to a format close to RFC 3339 / ISO 8601, like one of these:

`%F %T` → 2013-06-24 16:13:00

`%F %a %T` → 2013-06-24 Mon 16:13:00

`%A %F %T` → Monday 2013-06-24 16:13:00

I know Unity has a preference somewhere hidden away in dconf, this is how I did it in Unity, but I can't find such a preference for Gnome 3 shell. Preferably, I'd also like to set one of these as my system-wide date/time locale preference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure the clock date format to ISO 8601?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/237941/how-to-configure-the-clock-date-format-to-iso-8601)

Comment: @Radu: Unity shell is not Gnome shell. No, it's **not** a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Unfortunately, [tag:gnome-shell] is a synonym of [tag:gnome], when in fact it is only a _part_ of Gnome 3 that is replaced by Unity shell in main Ubuntu.

Comment: @edwin: Either _which_ way? I don't even have those 2 keys in my dconf. Maybe you should test it yourself, and if you succeed, post an answer back here. Until then, this question is **not** a duplicate of that one. As I mentioned in the question, I know it's possible in Unity, I've done it before, using those 2 keys, but this is Gnome shell. Can we move on now?

Comment: I have been looking [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2121784), [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~registry/gnome-shell/trunk/revision/5206#js/ui/dateMenu.js), and [here](http://www.roojs.org/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/seed/GnomeDesktop.WallClock.html#expand). Put so far (at least according to the last 'here') it looks like the API has been modified so the format is inside the C/C++ code. I mean I cannot find anything in the JavaScript API about the `WallClock` class (which you could use to change the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/dateMenu.js`).

Comment: @edwin: Thanks, that's useful. Maybe I might make an extension one day. :-)

Comment: You can browse the code [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-desktop/tree/gnome-3-6/libgnome-desktop) in the file `gnome-wall-clock.c` and its header, the API doesn't give you public methods to  deal with a custom clock format.

Comment: You can use localisation without the need to install any extensions, as explained: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096203/how-to-display-custom-formatted-clock-in-top-bar-on-multiple-displays-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 16):

Open a terminal and set

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true
```

YMMW - this did work for me on Fedora 19.

Comment: … and Fedora22!

Comment: The question is asking how to change the format of the date displayed (by the clock and in other places), not how to display the date next to the clock.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 too

Answer (score 11):

I was ultimately able to achieve my exactly desired format using a GNOME extension made by Daniel Khodabakhsh. Thank you Daniel!

I found that here:
https://github.com/Daniel-Khodabakhsh/datetime-format

Screenshot:
[image]

Format:
%A | %m-%d-%G | %I:%M %p

Comment: Where do you write that format? I see a lot of files and directories in the directory installed by that program, but I can't make much sense of it.

Comment: You write it right were it is shown in the screenshot, using Tweaks (Notice all 3 windows and their stack-order, in the screenshot). @Andyc

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what Martin says, the following worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04, where dconf-editor didn't:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
```

Comment: As with Martin's answer, the question is asking how to change the format of the date displayed (by the clock and in other places), not how to display the date next to the clock.

Comment: Fair point, additionally I should  probably have left this as a comment on Martin's response

Answer (score 4):

You can try one of these three extensions:

- [Full Clock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/281/full-clock/)

  > [image] Replaces the default clock with a complete one showing time, date and week day
- [Full Clock 2](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/896/full-clock-2/)

  > [image] Replaces the default clock with a one showing date, week, day of week and time.
- [Format Clock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/795/format-clock/) (development discontinued, but apparently working fine in 3.16)

  > [image] Change top panel clock format.

  It says the develpmont has been discontinued, but I tested it, manually editing `metadata.json` to include `3.18`, and it works:

  [image]

Comment: I am unable to install any of those because they do not seem to support 3.18 and it doesn't even seem to download them.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda [Format Clock is on Github](https://github.com/eternal-sorrow/format-clock) (see README for instructions), and you can try http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/76-gnome/283-gnome-shell-install-extension-command-line-script for the others.

Comment: And there is no way of changing any settings in `dconf-editor `or something to do this rather than installing something?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda nope. The only settings I can find are for just showing the date there.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

Although it doesn't look like the panel clock is easy to format, the calendar menu opened by clicking on it is very easy. Here's a quick hack:

```
$ sudo vim /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/dateMenu.js
```

(`vim` or any other text editor.)

Search for ‘`B %d, %Y`’, and replace with ‘`F`’. Save. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to restart the shell.

Searching the parent directory reveals a few others that might be worth experimenting with:

```
$ rgrep -I '%B' /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/
```

but unfortunately, searching for the abbreviated month name in the panel clock returns nothing here:

```
$ rgrep -I '%b' /usr/share/gnome-shell/
```

Any changes to these file will probably be overwritten by updates to Gnome, and you may want to keep the originals of files you edit (`sudo mv [name].js [name].js.orig`).

Comment: It's worth doing with `calendar.js` as well; there are 2 relevant lines in the `_showOtherDay` function.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 19.10:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-weekday true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
```

etc.

*Or*, run

```
dconf-editor
```

and go to `org.gnome.desktop.interface`. You will find `clock-show-weekday`, `clock-show-seconds`, `clock-show-date` and others.

Comment: Not an answer to the question