# How to create, configure and apply dconf custom keyfile/gschema for an existing Gnome 3 object?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, dconf, clock, gsettings

I want to customize the top panel date time format as a `strftime` string.

I have already achieved this by installing the very splendid 'Clock Override' extension, but looking at dconf documentation, it looks like there should be a simple way of customizing the clock myself with a keyfile and/or gschema.

I'm assuming that the top panel clock already has a keyfile somewhere, as the settings for clock-format (24h/12h), clock-show-date (b), clock-show-seconds (b) and clock-show-weekday (b) are present in `dconf` and can be managed via `gsettings`.

However the documentation doesn't seem to match the reality.
For example, the gnome documentation indicates that keyfiles should be placed into the `/etc/dconf/db/database.d/` directory, but that directory doesn't exist on my system, so where is dconf getting all it's keys from?

Can anyone please point me to some clear instructions or guidance on adding new settings to `dconf`?

### Alternative

I found a simple and elegant way to adjust the top panel date time format using localisation rather than extensions or `dconf` keyfile/gschema:

[How to display custom formatted clock in top bar on multiple displays in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096203/how-to-display-custom-formatted-clock-in-top-bar-on-multiple-displays-in-ubuntu)