# Date format isn't standardised across GNOME 3 system apps

Tags: 18.04, gnome, date

Having just enabled the Livepatch feature, I notice that it uses yet another non-standard date format.

The following **system apps use** these given **date & time formats**:

**Settings > Date & Time**
3 September 2019, 15:27

**Top Bar Wall Clock**
Tue Sep 3, 15:27

**Livepatch**
03/09/19 15:27

Is there any way to centralise and standardise a single date format to be used across all GNOME 3 applications? If the answer is (as I suspect) no, wouldn't this be something worth considering for an update?

Comment: Top Bar Wall Clock can be customized the way you want with clock-override gnome-shell extension.. I agree with you point.. We should not have to install extensions for centralizing the time format in all aspects..

Comment: Thanks @PRATAP, my preferred method of customising the top bar wall clock is, without extension, by actually implementing the correct Gnome Localisation (as should already be the case) - as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096203/how-to-display-custom-formatted-clock-in-top-bar-on-multiple-displays-in-ubuntu