# how to make the status bar to show both georgian date and persian(shamsi) date?

Tags: 20.04, customization, date, statusbar

Is there a way to make the status bar on the top the screen to show both georgian and persian date?

It would be really handy

Comment: [The answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1118423/1091774) might get you most of the way there 