# How to make date show day/month/year in numbers instead of letters and words?

Tags: customization, time, date

At the moment, this is how the date and clock looks like in Ubuntu's top bar:

[image: Date and clock in Ubuntu's top bar]

In Estonian, "R" stands for "Reede" or "Friday", and "Juuli" means "July".

How can I make the date show day/month/year in numbers instead of letters and words?

Comment: I prefer `date +"%Y-%m-%d"` and you can replace - by / or anything else, and change the order, so I think this command; `date +"%d/%m/%Y"` may be what you want. See `info date` for more details.

Comment: @Frappy Since you mentioned "Ubuntu's top bar". You most probably using default DE that is GNOME. You can install gnome shell extension for what you are looking for. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/

Comment: Sorry. I read 'date' in the title to mean the command line `date`. But UnKNOWn was reading your question more correctly.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Thank you! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1345507/618353) (not sure if it should be considered a duplicate), so I'm copying my answer from there, modifying the clock format to the one you want.

---

There are several extensions in the [GNOME Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) website, but most of them are not actively supported anymore. I'm suggesting you to use the [Panel Date Format](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3465/panel-date-format/) extension, which works fine on Ubuntu 20.04 and is still maintained.

- Read this question about how to install GNOME Shell extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)

To customize your clock after installing the extension, follow these steps:

1. Open Extensions, find the *Panel Date Format* extension in the list and click the gear icon next to it.
2. You will be presented with this *Preferences* menu (image from the extension's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/atareao/panel-date-format)):

   [image: preferences menu]
3. In the *Format* textbox enter the following to get the time format you want:

   ```
   %d/%m/%Y %H:%M
   ```

   You can find more info about the date time format syntax [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GLib-2.0/classes/DateTime.html#GLib.DateTime.format) (link also mentioned in the extension's preferences).
4. Restart GNOME Shell to ensure that the setting is applied by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, entering `r` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Your panel's clock should now have the appearance you want!